# Why was -F removed from /sbin/shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, fsck

I used to be able to run `/sbin/shutdown -r -F now` but in recent Ubuntu and Fedora releases there is no `-F` option and if I want to force an fsck I need to do `touch /forcefsck; /sbin/shutdown -r now`.  Why was it removed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This flag does not exist in Upstart's version of `shutdown`. Ubuntu migrated to using Upstart as its default init system in 6.10, when sysvinit was replaced.

See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/74139) for more information.

Comment: This also applies to systemd distros, such as Fedora.

Comment: @jordanm Sure, `-F` doesn't exist in most init system's versions of `shutdown`.